# Data upload required for cloud computing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, hardware

If I want to utilize Amazon Web Services to provide the hardware (cores and memory) to process a large amount of data, do I need to upload that data to AWS? Or can I keep the data on the system and rent the hardware?

Comment: Ideally the data is close to the compute e.g. in S3 or on EC2 EBS volumes. Which AWS services are you planning to use? How much data? Some AWS services will require data to be in AWS, but not all. If the data's reachable over the internet (VPN tunnel? Direct Connect?) and you're OK with the increased latency and reduced bandwidth then you might be OK. Need more info.

Comment: Oh we are just brainstorming about we could do 100% processing on all of our data in a timely manner. Right now we do statistically significant amount of the processing, just because by the time more data comes in from collection, we need the systems available. During collection season we process about 1.5 TB of data per week, so about 25 TB per year. At the end of collection season the data is then exported to the servers as a intranet web service for others in our organization.

Comment: I believe the internet connection we have in our office is 100 meg/s

Comment: I work for state level dept of transportation and the data is road surface quality data and images collected using data collection vans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in order for an AWS-managed system to process a large amount of data, you will need to upload the data to an AWS region for processing at some point. AWS does not rent out servers to other physical locations, as far as I'm aware (EDIT: actually, AWS does have an offering for on-premises data processing as of [Nov 30 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/announcing-aws-snowball-edge/), see [Snowball Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball-edge/)).

AWS offers a variety of services for getting large amounts of data into its data centers for processing, (ranging from basic HTTP uploads to physically mailing disk drives for direct data import), and the best service to use will depend entirely on your specific use-case, needs and budget. See the overview page at [Cloud Data Migration](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-data-migration/) for an overview of the various services and help on selecting the most appropriate service.